# how to reference generic objects if you can't define the type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics

I'm trying to make a custom config solution and needs to be able to add services as transient, but I can't figuer out how to reference a generic element when I don't know the type.

I add an element of type Transient which takes multiple TransientItem elements.
Later I wan't to iterate the items and add them to the service collection.

Sounds easy, but I must be missing something.

```
public interface ITransient : IAppFeatureBase
{
    IEnumerable<TransientItem<????>> Get();
}

public sealed class Transient : AppFeatureBase, ITransient
{
    private readonly ICollection<TransientItem<????>> _items = new Collection<TransientItem<?????>>();

    public Transient(params TransientItem<?????>[] items) : base(Features.Transient)
    {
        _items.AddRange(_items);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TransientItem<????>> Get() => _items;
}

public struct TransientItem<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public readonly IServiceCollection Add(IServiceCollection services) => services.AddTransient<TEntity>();
}

public struct TransientItem<TInterface, TEntity> where TInterface : class
                                                    where TEntity : class, TInterface
{
    public readonly IServiceCollection Add(IServiceCollection services) => services.AddTransient<TInterface, TEntity>();
}
```

This is where I configure the services:

```
foreach(Transient trans in features.Where(feat => feat.Type == Features.Transient))
{
    foreach(TransientItem<????> item in trans.Get())
    {
        item.Add(builder.Services);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "add services as transient" mean?

Comment: services.AddTransient<TInterface, TEntity>()

Comment: did I spell it wrong? but that's not the problem - how do I for example do a foreach on generic items?

Comment: Sorry, what's `services.AddTransient<TInterface, TEntity>()`?

Comment: You should read [ask], then improve your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: what don't you understand? I thought the code was self explanatory

Comment: Yes, I imagine you did. You're intimately familiar with your code. You know all of the libraries you're using, you know all of your design choices and you know your end goal. We don't. You need to explain everything in excruciating detail.

Comment: The bottom-line is you can't do what you're asking because constructors can't have generic elements added unless the class is generic. But, if you give us more information about what you're trying to do then perhaps we can offer alternative approaches.

Comment: I have this system for configuring an asp.net core site, I just define what features the site needs using different classes. What I want is a class or method where I can supply an interface and a class that inherits that interface, and then use these values to add the element to the DI as transient in the class where I do the configuring

Comment: If you can treat it as an "object", do so. And "builder.services" appears to have no relation to the "foreach's".

Comment: @SteinTheRuler - So a DI container that you can register a concrete instance to an interface and in another piece of your code pull out that concrete instance based on the interface alone?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes exactly! I'll try to store them in a Dictionary object as suggested below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom-line is you can't do what you're asking because constructors can't have generic elements added unless the class is generic.

But, based on the comments, it sounds like you're just trying to create a service locator container that you can register a concrete instance to an interface and in another piece of your code pull out that concrete instance based on the interface.

Here's the kind of code I do for that:

```
public sealed class Registry 
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _items = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Register<I>(I instance)
    {
        _items[typeof(I)] = instance;
    }

    public I Resolve<I>() => (I)_items[typeof(I)];

    public bool TryResolve<I>(out I instance)
    {
        if (_items.ContainsKey(typeof(I)))
        {
            instance = (I)_items[typeof(I)];
            return true;
        }
        instance = default(I);
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, now, I have these interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class Foo : IFoo { }

public interface IBar { }
public class Bar : IBar { }
```

I can use them like this:

```
var registry = new Registry();
registry.Register<IFoo>(new Foo());
registry.Register<IBar>(new Bar());

/* somewhere else in the code */

IFoo foo = registry.Resolve<IFoo>();

if (registry.TryResolve<IBar>(out IBar bar))
{
    /* do something with `bar` */
}
```

Comment: To be clear, what you’re describing isn’t DI, it’s the classic service locator anti-pattern. But yes, that’s what OP seems to want.

Comment: @Blindy - You're correct. It's not DI. It's not actually injecting.